# Powershell - how to extract a value from Object[]

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the value associated with AzureWebJobsStorage variable from a Object[] in powershell.  Here's the logic so far:

```
 $azAppSettingsOutput = az functionapp config appsettings list --name somename --resource-group myResource --subscription subscription | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $azAppSettingsOutput.GetType().name
Write-Output $azAppSettingsOutput | Get-Member
Write-Output $azAppSettingsOutput.name
```

This is the output I see:

```
PS C:\Users\me> .\test.ps1
Object[]

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty string name=APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
slotSetting NoteProperty bool slotSetting=False
value       NoteProperty string value=asdfasdf-asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf

APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
AzureWebJobsStorage
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE
StorageTableName

PS C:\Users\me\>
```

I know I can loop through like this:

```
foreach($setting in $azAppSettingsOutput) {
    Write-Output $setting.name
    $value = $setting.value
```

And then I can add an if statement to check if the name matches "AzureWebJobsStorage" but just wondering if there's a simpler way.

Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance on the matter: doesn't the azure cli return text? Couldn't you use `Get-AzFunctionApp` to return an object already instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter your data:

```
$azAppSettingsOutput |Where-Object name -eq 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
```

This will filter out any objects except for those where the `name` property equals `"AzureWebJobsStorage"`